# Using class from module gives no attribute error?

Tags: python

In the file `beam.py` I wrote a class as follows:

```
class beam(object):
    def __init__(self, u0, dT, maxT):
        self.u0 = u0
        self.dT = dT
        self.maxT = maxT

    def nMmethod(self):
        print(self.u0, self.dT, self.maxT)
```

When this is finished I use this class in a different script:

```
import beam as bm

bm.nMmethod()
```

But it throws an AttributeError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./callBeam.py", line 3, in <module>
    bm.nMmethod()
AttributeError: module 'beam' has no attribute 'nMmethod'
```

But I did define `nMmethod` in the `beam` class?

Comment: instantiate the class first, something like `b=bm()`. Though your `nMmethod` only takes the `self` argument, but you pass it `u0`?

Comment: @SuperStew you mean `b = bm.nMmethod(u0)?`

Comment: No. `b=bm()` then later `b.nMmethod(u0)`

Comment: I changed to:  

`b = bm()`
`b.nMmethod(u0)`

and it gives me:
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import beam as bm
```

This line imports the module `beam`, then renames it to `bm`. The module `bm` does not have a method named `nMmethod`. The *class* `beam` has a method named `nMmethod`, but you are not accessing the class when you do `bm.nMmethod`.

Try creating a `beam` instance and calling `nMmethod` on that.

```
x = bm.beam(1, 2, 3) #or whatever the arguments should be
x.nMmethod()
```